# Pivot Table Format throws Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format the results of a pivot table using the "Accounting" number format w/o the currency tick.  I copied the number formatting type directly from the format cells box and entered it into my vba as shown below:

`.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* " - "??_);_(@_)"`

This throws the Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch.  I've tried copying and pasting other formats and it works just fine, e.g.

`.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"`

I'm guessing this has something to do with the asterisks in the format, but I'm just not well versed enough to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I played around with it some more and found the issue. Contrary to what I initially thought, it doesn't have to do with the asterisks, but with the nested quotation marks.  If you remove the inner quotation marks altogether, it formats as expected:

This works: `.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(*  - ??_);_(@_)"`

This does not work:`.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(*  "-" ??_);_(@_)"`

Comment: If anyone is willing to offer some guidance on _why_ nested quotes cause this error, I'm interested.